# What would be GQLAlchemy, Python, way to create relationship in graph database?

Tags: memgraphdb

In Cypher, when I create a relationship, I use CREATE clause. To show that there is a connection between the two cities, I would use something like:

```
CREATE (:City {name: 'London'})-[:CONNECTED_WITH]->(:City {name: 'Dublin'});
```

How can this be done in Python using GQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating relationships is done with methods `to()` and `from()` that needs to come after `create()`. So the example from above would look in Python like this:

```
from gqlalchemy import Create

query = Create()
        .node(labels="City", name="London")
        .to(relationship_type="CONNECTED_WITH")
        .node(labels="City", name="Dublin")
        .execute()
```